# What happens if someone violates a political party's "contribution rules" (which might be laws, I'm not sure)?

Tags: united-states, minor, oregon, campaign-finance

[The Oregon Republican Party's donation page](https://secure.winred.com/oregon-republican-party/donate) lists rules, including:

> I am at least eighteen years old. I am not, nor am I making this contribution on behalf of, a corporation, labor organization, national bank, foreign national without a green card, a federal contractor, or any other federally impermissible source.

What happens if a minor donates without reading these rules?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing happens to the minor. The recipient does not get in trouble because the minor did not read the assertions, they might get in trouble if the contributor is [not allowed](https://www.fec.gov/help-candidates-and-committees/candidate-taking-receipts/who-can-and-cant-contribute/) to make said contribution, for example "is a foreign national". There are certain steps to take [if a contribution is questionable](https://www.fec.gov/help-candidates-and-committees/candidate-taking-receipts/questionable-contributions/), for example refund it or ascertain that the contribution is legal. Since the question asks the pertinent questions, the contributions is *not* questionable, unless some other direct evidence is brought to the attention of the committee.

The inclusion of minors in this instance is out of an "abundance of caution". Minors *can* contribute, but there are restrictions, that

> The decision to contribute is made knowingly and voluntarily by the
> minor;
>
> The funds, goods or services contributed are owned or controlled by
> the minor, proceeds from a trust for which he or she is a beneficiary
> or funds withdrawn by the minor from a financial account opened and
> maintained in his or her name; and
>
> The contribution is not made using funds given to the minor as a gift
> for the purpose of making the contribution, and is not in any way
> controlled by another individual.

I suppose they feel that it is too risky to accept contributions by minors: such an exclusion is not required by federal law.

Comment: Thank you! Is the minor eligible for the tax credit? The contribution was made in compliance with that law.

Comment: If indeed the contribution was in compliance with state law etc. etc. then making a donation contrary to an extra-legal desire of the donee doesn't invalidate the credit.